# Creating View from Two Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a view to pull data from two tables.

**Invoices**

Invoice

Job

Vendor

**InvoiceItems**

Invoice

Job

Quantity

The issue here is for invoices table Job field does not get populated. So I need to grab the Job Field from InvoiceItems table. However InvoiceItems have multiple record for each invoice or Job.

The view I am currently using is created as

```
**Create view dbo.invoicesjob
as
select i.invoice, max(j.job) as JobNumber
from invoices i left outer join invoiceitems j on i.invoice=j.invoice
group by i.invoice**
```

Is it the right way to pull from invoiceitems table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: Changed group by to both invoice and job

Try this

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.invoicesjob
     as
select 
     i.invoice, 
     j.job as 'JobNumber'
from invoices i left outer join 

(select 
   invoice, 
   job
 from invoiceitems
 group by invoice, job) j 
 on i.invoice=j.invoice
```

You can add your Where statement below.

```
 where i.status = 'pending'
```

Or if you want to a more performance friendly approach:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.invoicesjob
     as
  select 
     i.invoice, 
     j.job as 'JobNumber'
  from 
    (select invoice
     from invoices 
     where i.status = 'pending') i 
  left outer join 
    (select 
     invoice, 
     job
     from invoiceitems
     group by invoice, job) j 
  on i.invoice=j.invoice
```

Comment: I get this error on running this statement "Column 'invoiceitems.Job' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I updated it, because I forgot to group by both columns. Try the new updated script.

Comment: Is there a way we can add another condition while selecting from Invoices table only those records for which the Status is Pending.There is a field on Invoices table called status and I need to pull pending Invoices only along with the Job Number from InvoiceItems.

Comment: You can add the where statement after the join  ... where i.status = 'pending'

Comment: Okay that worked. Both the answers are correct.. Thankss a lott :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks right. I'm assuming that the `invoice` column is the primary key, or a unique key, in the `invoices` table. Otherwise, the GROUP BY operation is going to collapse rows. (Not that there's anything wrong with collapsing rows, it really depends on your requirements.)

Your query will get you the rows from `Invoices` along with a `JobNumber` obtained from `invoiceitems`, if one is available. If no matching rows are available from `invoiceitems`, the query will return a NULL for the `JobNumber` column.

In the more general case, when you don't want a `GROUP BY` on the query for some reason (e.g. you don't want to collapse any rows from the `invoices` table), you can get a single JobNumber for each `invoice` in an inline view...

```
SELECT i.invoice
     , j.jobnumber
  FROM invoices i
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT k.invoice
              , MAX(k.job) AS jobnumber
           FROM invoiceitems k
          GROUP BY k.invoice
       ) j
    ON j.invoice = i.invoice
```

But again, if `invoice` is the primary key or a unique key from `invoices` table, then this will return a result equivalent to the query in your view definition. There won't be any difference.

Comment: This is pretty much same what I posted in definition. I think it is getting me the what I need but just wanted to confirm.